# How can I show you the files already stored on server using Dropzone.js

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I Don't understand that... `call` its always undefined

Create the mock file:

```
var mockFile = { name: "Filename", size: 12345 };
```

Call the default addedfile event handler

```
myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
```

And optionally show the thumbnail of the file:

```
myDropzone.options. thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, "/image/url");
```

Comment: The parameters of createThumbnailFromUrl has changed in Version > 5. To make it work again, check out this GitHub Issue: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/1587#issuecomment-324023260

Answer (score 48):

Finally !!

```
$(function() {
    var mockFile = { name: "banner2.jpg", size: 12345 };
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone");
    myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
    myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, "http://localhost/test/drop/uploads/banner2.jpg");
})
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the files added with this method behave somewhat differently from the "regular" ones. For one, I don't seem to be able to get rid of them when calling .removeAllFiles() on the dropzone instance. I posted this as a question in case someone wants to contribute: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369291/dropzone-js-removeallfiles-does-not-remove-mock-files

Comment: that's because you haven't actually added any files to the files array. Use thisDropzone.files.push(mockFile);

Comment: @dan where to add push function, i added below thumbnail.call but its not working.

Comment: Does this code add an existing thumbnail? Or is dropzone creating a new one on the fly?

Comment: The problem with this is it doesn't size down the photo to a thumbnail view, instead it just shows the top left corner of the photo....

Comment: Do the remove link work. I tried addRemoveLinks: true but all it does for the preexisting files on server was remove it from the Dropzone and does not initiate removedfile function but works fine on the work uploaded.

Comment: I think a better, more updated answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31627155/5221039

Answer (score 44):

You can also do with the following code:

```
  <script>
        Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = false;
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        $("#image").dropzone({
            url: "http://someserver.com/upload.php",
            paramName: "image", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
            maxFilesize: 2, // MB
            maxFiles: 5,
            parallelUploads: 5,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            dictMaxFilesExceeded: "You can only upload upto 5 images",
            dictRemoveFile: "Delete",
            dictCancelUploadConfirmation: "Are you sure to cancel upload?",
            accept: function (file, done) {
                console.log(file)
                if ((file.type).toLowerCase() != "image/jpg" &&
                        (file.type).toLowerCase() != "image/gif" &&
                        (file.type).toLowerCase() != "image/jpeg" &&
                        (file.type).toLowerCase() != "image/png"
                        ) {
                    done("Invalid file");
                }
                else {
                    done();
                }
            },
            init: function () {
                var mockFile = { name: "myimage.jpg", size: 12345, type: 'image/jpeg' };
                this.addFile.call(this, mockFile);
                this.options.thumbnail.call(this, mockFile, "http://someserver.com/myimage.jpg");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

**EDIT**

Since update of Dropzone 4.0 `init` function can be called as:

```
init: function () {
   var mockFile = { name: "myimage.jpg", size: 12345, type: 'image/jpeg' };       
   this.options.addedfile.call(this, mockFile);
   this.options.thumbnail.call(this, mockFile, "http://someserver.com/myimage.jpg");
   mockFile.previewElement.classList.add('dz-success');
   mockFile.previewElement.classList.add('dz-complete');
}
```

Comment: fwiw, i found that `addFile` errors in chrome on the latest v of dropzone, using `options.addedfile.call` worked instead

Comment: How can i cancel the removeLink on manual added file(s)? Please help

Comment: @Adobe Can u be more specific?

Comment: @Vicky Gonsalves Ok. Your solution provide to add existing files in Dropzone. I have on init event "addRemoveLinks" in TRUE. So all pre-added files with "delete link". But how to diable "romoveLink" for pre-added files?

Comment: If you know which are the pre added files, you can always prevent it from being deleted with if.. Else... Condition

Comment: @Vicky Gonsalves I can't do real delete because "removedfile" event not always executing (dunno why). I tried do like that: **this.addRemoveLinks = false;** but addRemoveLinks in TRUE

Answer (score 24):

my solution for >= 4.0, basing on "How to show files already stored on server": https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ

```
maxFiles: 1,

init: function () {
    this.on('maxfilesexceeded', function (file) {
        this.removeAllFiles();
        this.addFile(file);
    });

    var mocks = $dropzone.data('dropzone');
    for (var i = 0; i < mocks.length; i++) {
        var mock = mocks[i];
        mock.accepted = true;

        this.files.push(mock);
        this.emit('addedfile', mock);
        this.createThumbnailFromUrl(mock, mock.url);
        this.emit('complete', mock);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the right answer in my opinion, it handles correctly the use of `resize` and `maxFiles` options

Comment: How to specify the thumbnail style? I have created a B&W versions that I would like to show as thumbnails, how to do that?

Comment: My problem was that thumbnail of my file was being shown partially, i was using "this.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, item.Path);" . I replaced this with "this.createThumbnailFromUrl(mock, mock.url);" and it worked.

Answer (score 12):

Based on punky's excellent answer above, you should not forget to add `this._updateMaxFilesReachedClass();` at the end, like so:

```
init: function () {
    var mockFile = { name: <filename>, size: <filesize>, type: <filetype>, url: <file_url> };
    this.files.push(mockFile);
    this.emit('addedfile', mockFile);
    this.createThumbnailFromUrl(mockFile, mockFile.url);
    this.emit('complete', mockFile);
    this._updateMaxFilesReachedClass();
}
```

Comment: In order to get it working it is necessary to set the file as accepted, otherwise the event **maxfilesreached** is not emitted (see _updateMaxFilesReachedClass code).

A quick solution is to add **accepted: true** to the mockFile. What do you think?

Comment: @MauroNidola You are right. There is no point in using `this._updateMaxFilesReachedClass();` if you do not add `accepted: true` to the mockFile.

Answer (score 7):

In this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17763511, it's implemeneted with emmiting a **thumbnail** event.

Following is an example of doing it using **[createThumbnailFromUrl](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ#how-to-show-files-already-stored-on-server)**.

HTML element;

```
<form id="sample-img" action="/upload" class="dropzone">
    <div class="dz-default dz-message"></div>
</form>
```

JS code;

```
previewThumbailFromUrl({
    selector: 'sample-img',
    fileName: 'sampleImg',
    imageURL: '/images/sample.png'
});

function previewThumbailFromUrl(opts) {
    var imgDropzone = Dropzone.forElement("#" + opts.selector);
    var mockFile = {
        name: opts.fileName,
        size: 12345,
        accepted: true,
        kind: 'image'
    };
    imgDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
    imgDropzone.files.push(mockFile);
    imgDropzone.createThumbnailFromUrl(mockFile, opts.imageURL, function() {
        imgDropzone.emit("complete", mockFile);
    });
}
```

**Working Samples on JSFiddle:**

1. [Load images on same domain](https://jsfiddle.net/gihanchanuka/pp66q18p/1)
2. [Load images with crossOrigin](https://jsfiddle.net/gihanchanuka/6gksmdrr/1/)

Comment: Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.

Comment: @Justin, here is a working example of my above code https://jsfiddle.net/gihanchanuka/pp66q18p/1 . Since you got a Cross-Origin issue over HTTPS doesn't mean that above code is not working for same domain image URLs. As you can clearly see through my answer `imageURL: '/images/sample.png'`, it's referring to an image which is in same domain. This is a solution which is built on my knowledge. You can seek for other solutions as well. Here is more about your Error http://stackoverflow.com/a/27840082/1461060. Hope this will help you!

Comment: @Justin I have looked into the DropzoneJS implementation https://github.com/antpaw/dropzone/blob/2a960cf89c70b0eb8b73d65fbbcc56cce9ae516f/src/dropzone.coffee#L1009 , and figured out the issue that you unable to solve. DropzoneJS is allowing to pass configuration for `crossOrigin`. Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img. I have updated the answer with `crossOrigin` option as well. https://jsfiddle.net/gihanchanuka/6gksmdrr/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
 var mockFile = { name: "banner2.jpg", size: 12345, uuid: "085b2b23-70e7-4175-8355-89937d8d46f2" };
 myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
 myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, "https://your-thumbnail-image.jpg");
```

On Init-Function of the Dropzone-Object   init: function() { call this:

```
this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
  //Access the preview element with file.previewElement and add event listeners, etc... to it.
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('href',"{{{protokoll}}}://{{{HTTP_HOST}}}/a-getfiledb.php?uuid="+file.uuid);
  a.setAttribute('class',"btn btn-success");
  a.setAttribute('style',"width:50%; margin-top:5px; border-left:1px solid black; cursor:pointer;");
  a.innerHTML = "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt'></i>";
  file.previewTemplate.appendChild(a);
});
```

Comment: This code shows existing images already uploaded on the server in the Dropzone box. However, when I tried to re-upload these images, they are not recognized as being in the queue. this.getQueuedFiles().length , and myDropzone.getUploadingFiles().length both returns 0. I am using dropzone5.5.0.js. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I was having hard time with this also. This one as a starting point would have helped even more:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false; // otherwise will be initialized twice
var myDropzoneOptions = {
    maxFilesize: 5,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    clickable: true
};
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#myDropzoneElement', myDropzoneOptions);
var mockFile = { name: "Existing file!", size: 12345 };
myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, "http://url-to-thumb-goes-here");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with this

```
var file_image = "http://someserver.com/myimage.jpg";

var mockFile = { name: "myimage.jpg", size: 12345 };

$("#dropzone").dropzone({

    url: 'false',
    maxFiles: 1,
    maxFilesize:10,//mb
    acceptedFiles:'image/*',
    init: function() {
        this.on("addedfile", function(file){
            this.options.thumbnail.call(this,file,file_image);
         });
         this.addFile.call(this,mockFile);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
 import vue2Dropzone from 'vue2-dropzone'
    import 'vue2-dropzone/dist/vue2Dropzone.min.css'
    export default {
        created(){
            let app = this;
            app.getAdvertById()
        },
         data: function () {
            return {
                advertId: null,
                advert: {
                    title: '',
                    description: '',
                    confirm: '',
                    files: {},
                    category:'',
                    city:''
                },
               
                adverts: [],
                   dropzoneOptions: {
                    url: 'https://httpbin.org/post',
                    thumbnailWidth: 150,
                    addRemoveLinks: true,
                    maxFilesize: 0.5,
                    dictDefaultMessage: 'Plz add your image here...',
                    headers: { "My-Awesome-Header": "header value" }
                },
            }
        },
          methods: {
            getAdvertById(){
                let app = this;
                let id = app.$route.params.id;
                app.advertId = id;
                axios.get('/api/v1/advert/show/' + app.advertId)
                    .then(function (resp) {
                        app.advert = resp.data
                        app.advert.files = resp.data.files
                         for (var i = 0; i < app.advert.files.length; i++) {
                            var mockFile = {id: app.advert.files[i].id, name: app.advert.files[i].file_name, size: app.advert.files[i].size};
                            app.$refs.myVueDropzone.manuallyAddFile(mockFile, '/advert/' + app.advert.files[i].file_name )
                            app.$refs.myVueDropzone.dropzone.options.thumbnail.call(app.$refs.myVueDropzone, mockFile, '/advert/' + app.advert.files[i].file_name)
                            if (app.$refs.myVueDropzone.dropzone.options.maxFiles > 0) {
                                app.$refs.myVueDropzone.dropzone.options.maxFiles--
                            }
                            }
                    })
                    .catch(function () {
                        alert("Could not load your advert")
                    });
                    //console.log(app.advert.files)
            },
          }
        }
```

```html
 <vue-dropzone  ref="myVueDropzone" id="dropzone" :options="dropzoneOptions"></vue-dropzone>
```

Comment: Answers are generally better received when you add some context or explain them, instead of just dropping code.