# dropzone.js .removeAllFiles() does not remove mock files

Tags: dropzone.js

I noticed that when calling .removeAllFiles() on a dropzone instance that received "mock" files using the technique as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17763511/531103) does not actually have the desired effect (the mock file is still present).

Answer (score 21):

I also had the same problem.
I thinks it happens because the files which are added from the server does not go into the files array and when you call `removeAllFiles()` it won't work because it is not in the files array atall. 
So the obvious solution would be to add them into the files array,it would look something like this

```
$(function() {
    var mockFile = { name: "banner2.jpg", size: 12345 };
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone");
    myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
    myDropzone.files.push(mockFile); // here you add them into the files array
    myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile,
        "http://localhost/test/drop/uploads/banner2.jpg");
});
```

Now you can use `myDropzone.removeAllFiles();` on some event and the files added from server will also get removed from dropzone.

**NOTE: Remember when using the above code. if you are firing a server side code to delete the files from server whenever a file is removed from dropzone then all the files that came from the server will get deleted.**

Comment: I would vote you up twice if i could, THANK YOU for this!! Ive been bashing my head against the wall.

Comment: For the mockFile. Include "accepted: true" or if you have set the maxFiles number, the counter will not be sync with the number of files added programmatically. Means, if you add 3 files with maxFiles set to 3, the first 3 files added manually will not be counted.