# how to display the image in dropzone from database in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i want to display the image from the database in dropzone. 
here is my view page :

```
<div class="col-md-6"> <b>Challenge Banner</b>
    <form class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="#" action="<?php echo base_url(''); ?>Challenge/file_upload" enctype="" method="post">
        <div class="dz-message text-center" style='height:80px;'>
            <div class="drag-icon-cph"> <i class="material-icons" style='font-size:36px;'>touch_app</i> 
            </div>
            <h6>Drop files here or click to upload.</h6>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

i want to display image from data base.. how i can upload the image?

Comment: where u want to display and where is your database query?

Comment: i want to know how to display image in dropzone

Comment: pls see this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759286/how-can-i-show-you-the-files-already-stored-on-server-using-dropzone-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I show you the files already stored on server using Dropzone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759286/how-can-i-show-you-the-files-already-stored-on-server-using-dropzone-js)